# Does iOS have a similar function like the "Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility"?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have many markers to place on a Google map. I hope markers can be clustered on the map but I didn't find any function in Google map documentation for iOS. The Android API has a “Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility”. What should I do to achieve similar functionality？

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/infinum/FBAnnotationClustering